# Gulpfile not compiling @includes and @imports

Tags: javascript, sass, gulp, zurb-foundation, gulp-sass

I'm creating a gulpfile to compile a long list of `scss` files and minify them.
My problem is that my `sass` `@import`s and `@include`s are being completely ignored, while the rest of the file is compiled and minified without a problem.

Here's what my `gulpfile.js` looks like.

```js
const
  gulp = require('gulp'),
  plugins = require('gulp-load-plugins')({lazy:false}),
  sass = require('gulp-sass'),
  postcss = require('gulp-postcss'),
  autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer'),
  cssnano = require('gulp-cssnano'),
  sourcemaps = require('gulp-sourcemaps');

const paths = {
  scss: {
    src: './assets/scss/stylesheet.scss',
    dest: './assets/css/',
    watch: './assets/scss/**/*.scss'
  }
}

function styling() {
  return gulp
    .src(paths.scss.src)
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.init())
    .pipe(plugins.sass({ includePaths: paths.scss.includePaths }))
    .pipe(plugins.cssnano())
    .pipe(plugins.autoprefixer(paths.autoprefixer))
    .pipe(plugins.sourcemaps.write())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(paths.scss.dest))
    .on("error", sass.logError);
}

function watch() {
  gulp.watch(paths.scss.watch, styling);
}

exports.styling = styling;
exports.watch = watch;
```

This is Gulp 4 btw.

Here's my file structure:

```
assets/
  - scss
    - components
    - forms
    - grid
    - prototype
    - settings
    - typography
    - util
    - vendor
    - xy-grid
    - _global.scss
    - foundation.scss
    - stylesheet.scss
  - css
    - stylesheet.css
  - js
    - foundation.min.js
    - scripts.js
gulpfile.js
```

As you can see, I'm using foundation as a framework for this project.

If anyone can find where my code is being wonky, I thank you in advance!

Comment: You have `paths.scss.includePaths` in your `styling` task but I don't see it declared anywhere.

Comment: @Mark `paths` is a constant that contains the source/export/watch paths. It's located underneath where my plugins are declared.

Comment: Yes I see that, but there is no `paths.scss.includePaths` element of that variable.  You call that in your `styling` task and it looks like it doesn't exist.  You probably don't need it anyway depending on how your `stylesheet.scss~ is written but having it be undefined must be bad.